# Azure - Kudu - push changes back to git

Tags: git, azure, kudu

I've got the automatic build and deployment setup on Azure. Everything works fine.

However there is a certain file that if it get's modified during the build I would like it to be commited/pushed back to GIT. Is it possible with the current functionality of Kudu on Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not designed for this type of workflows. While you could probably hack something with some effort, you will at least need to solve auth.

Kudu has two different auth behaviors:

1. When deploying public repos, it uses the public https endpoint to pull changes. Hence it would not be able to push anything back.
2. When deploying private repos, it sets up a 'Deploy key' (with either GitHub or Bitbucket). But that deploy key only allows pulling. Related info [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment#setting-up-continuous-deployment-using-manual-steps)

So you would likely need to set Kudu up with a full ssh key, which can be done.

Once you're past auth and have the ability to push, you should be able to put something together with a post deployment action that does what you need.

But overall, I would not recommend such workflow.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to hear that I wasn't alone thinking this is not a good way to go :)